How to find MUI Select Component in Jest test - getByID/Name/Role not working
So I have this component, where I want to access the rendered MUI Select components value property to test.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import languageOptions from '../../utils/languageOptions';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import FooterGreyButton from '../buttons/FooterGreyButton';

function LanguageChanger({ onChange, initialLanguage }) {

    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(initialLanguage || 'en-GB');
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [maxHeight, setMaxHeight] = useState('500px');  // Default max height

// Handle Language Selection

    useEffect(() => {
        if (initialLanguage) {
            setSelectedValue(initialLanguage);
            onChange(initialLanguage);
        }
    }, [initialLanguage, onChange]);
    
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        setSelectedValue(value);
        onChange(value);
        console.log('value:', value);
    };

// Handles Dynamic Dropdown Menu Height

    const handleResize = () => {
        const dropdown = document.getElementById('language-changer-dropdown');
        if (dropdown) {
            const rect = dropdown.getBoundingClientRect();
            const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
            const dynamicDifference = viewportHeight - rect.top + 33;
            const dynamicMaxheight = viewportHeight - dynamicDifference;
            setMaxHeight(dynamicMaxheight + 'px');
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        handleResize();
    
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };
    }, []);

// Options

    const customOptions = languageOptions.map((language) => ({
        value: language.value,
        label: language.label
    }));

// Menu Open/ Close

    const toggleMenu = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };

// Footer Button Links

    const handleHelpButtonClicked = () => {
        window.open('https://support.google.com/accounts?hl=en-GB&visit_id=638451420796909083-2011793641&rd=2&p=account_iph#topic=3382296', '_blank');
    };

    const handlePrivacyButtonClicked = () => {
        window.open('https://policies.google.com/privacy?gl=GB&hl=en-GB', '_blank');
    };

    const handleTermsButtonClicked = () => {
        window.open('https://policies.google.com/terms?gl=GB&hl=en-GB', '_blank');
    };

    return (

        <div id='language-changer-footer'>
            <FormControl 
                role='combobox'
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                id='language-changer-dropdown'
                data-testid='language-changer-dropdown'
                sx={{
                        backgroundColor: open ? '#eeeeee' : '',
                        borderRadius: '4px',
                }}
                
            >
                <Select
                    role='language-selector-dropdown'
                    open={open}
                    id='language-selector'
                    aria-expanded={open}
                    onClose={() => setOpen(false)} 
                    onOpen={() => setOpen(true)} 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    data-testid='language-selector-dropdown'
                    displayEmpty={true}
                    value={selectedValue}
                    aria-label={selectedValue}
                    name='language-selector-dropdown'
                    inputProps={{
                        'data-testid': 'language-selector-dropdown',
                        'name': 'language-selector-dropdown'
                    }}
                    MenuProps={{
                        anchorOrigin: {
                            vertical: 'top',
                            horizontal: 'left'
                            },
                        transformOrigin: {
                            vertical: 'bottom',
                            horizontal: 'left'
                        },
                        getContentAnchorEl: () => document.getElementById('language-changer-dropdown'),
                        PaperProps: {
                            style: {
                                maxHeight: maxHeight,
                            },
                        },
                    }}
                    sx={{
                        '& .MuiSelect-icon': {
                            color: '#202124',
                        },
                        fontSize: '12px',   
                        boxShadow: 'none',
                        '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': { 
                            border: 0 
                        },
                        '&.MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                            border: 0,
                        },
                        '&.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                            border: 0,
                        },
                        paddingRight: '25px',
                    }}
                >
                    {customOptions.map(option => (
                        <MenuItem 
                            key={option.value} 
                            value={option.value}
                            sx={{
                                fontSize: '12px',
                                padding: '14px',
                                color: 'rgb(60,64,67)',
                            }}
                        >
                            {option.label}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>

            <nav id='footer-trio-buttons-container' aria-label='Footer links' role='navigation'>
                <FooterGreyButton role='button' onClick={handleHelpButtonClicked}>
                    Help
                </FooterGreyButton>
                <FooterGreyButton role='button' onClick={handlePrivacyButtonClicked}>
                    Privacy
                </FooterGreyButton>
                <FooterGreyButton role='button' onClick={handleTermsButtonClicked}>
                    Terms
                </FooterGreyButton>
            </nav>

        </div>

    );
}

export default LanguageChanger;

Now in my test I have tried getByName/Id/Role, async awaiting findByName,Id/Role
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import LanguageChanger from './LanguageChangerComponent';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import languageOptions from '../../utils/languageOptions';

const mockOnChange = jest.fn();

const mockUserData = { 
  language: 'en-GB' 
};

describe('LanguageChanger', () => {
  test('renders without crashing', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<LanguageChanger initialLanguage={mockUserData.language} onChange={mockOnChange}/>);
    const comboBox = getByTestId('language-changer-dropdown'); // Assuming this is the data-testid of the intended combobox
    expect(comboBox).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('selectedValue should be a valid language option or en-GB', async () => {
    const initialLanguage = 'fr-FR'; // You can change this to test with different initial languages
    const { rerender, findByTestId, findByRole } = render(<LanguageChanger initialLanguage={initialLanguage} onChange={mockOnChange}/>);
  
    rerender();

    let selectElement = await findByRole('language-selector-dropdown');
  
    if (!selectElement) {
      selectElement = await findByTestId('language-selector-dropdown');
    }

    // Access the selected value (assuming selectElement is found)
    if (selectElement) {
      const selectedValue = selectElement.value;
      expect(languageOptions.some(option => option.value === selectedValue) || selectedValue === 'en-GB').toBeTruthy();
    } else {
      // Handle the case where the element is not found (optional)
      console.error('Select element not found in the rendered component');
    }
  });
});

but every time I get
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid/name/role="language-selector-dropdown"]

but if i apply the same logic to a non MUI component eg a div it finds it no problem.
Is it because of MUI it won't work?
